# What's the point of drivers that can produce frequencies that humans can't hear?

Tags: frequency, frequency-response, high-frequency

Why companies advertise drivers with frequencies that most humans can't hear? I saw some headphones that says they can produce 10Hz-25kHz. I even saw one that can go up to 40kHz. Music formats also supports higher and lower frequencies. But what's the point? Most humans can't hear those frequencies. Is there any benefit to having those?

Comment: It's a way to show that the driver has super-flat frequency response in the audible range by design, It's like saying the driver reproduces the 20KHz without any roll-off close to it. It's a claim between truth and marketing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my humle mind it is purely marketing. People tend to buy on specifications, and bigger numbers sort of makes the user accept a higher price and hence a higher profit for the seller.

There can be a difference of course, in that close to the maximum frequency supported by the headphones or speakers, the sound might become attenuated or distorted which you might perceive. So in that case a higher max frequency may be better.

But in some cases, what the headphones or speakers will reproducera is only spurious noise and oscillations which would be better not to reproduce.

As they say, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3):

One reason may be  there is a need for them besides the use for  human listening.

Perhaps a human may want to study or devote their careers to  [Animal audiology](https://hearinghealthmatters.org/pathways/2019/animal-audiology-question-answer/).

If you want to study    an animal that has the ability to hear frequencies above or below what humans can hear then you may want a driver capable of producing frequencies in the range that the subject can hear in order to  do some scientific studies.